# Can Microsoft Office products be purchased (legally) online, downloaded and installed without needing media?

Tags: download

I need to purchase PowerPoint 2010 and install it on another pc over vpn. So I guess the order would be:

1. vpn to remote pc
2. open remote browser
3. purchase and download
4. then install

I need help with step 3. Can it be done? Where at?

Comment: I hope that nobody would try to purchase illegal stuff online, as you may never know what you might get after you pay for it! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can buy them directly from Microsoft, and Dell also allows you to buy them as download versions.

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/list/categoryID.50726400?Icid=OffCat_CMod_OfcStandAlone_Cat_50726400

Comment: I have done this with full Office. They send you the Key and a download link.